# cointegration using numpy, xlrd: keep getting a particular error

Tags: python, numpy, statsmodels, xlrd, quantitative-finance

I am trying to see whether some commodity pairs are cointegrated. However, I am encountering something very strange. The code that I have works with one excel file but doesn't work with another, more comprehensive one. Instead, it throws the following errors:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/test.py", line 28, in <module>
    score, pvalue, _ = coint(sb,kc)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/stattools.py", line 1009, in coint
    xx = add_trend(y1, trend=trend, prepend=False)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/tsatools.py", line 98, in add_trend
    col_const = np.logical_and(np.any(np.ptp(np.asanyarray(x), axis=0) == 0, axis=0),
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 2151, in ptp
    return _wrapfunc(a, 'ptp', axis=axis, out=out)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 67, in _wrapfunc
    return _wrapit(obj, method, *args, **kwds)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 47, in _wrapit
    result = getattr(asarray(obj), method)(*args, **kwds)
TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type
```

I am unable to understand what's happening, especially since the formatting of the two files is exactly the same.

Any insights as to what might be happening here would be greatly appreciated.

Below is my code for reference:

```
import numpy as np
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import coint
import os
import xlrd
cwd = os.getcwd()
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook("price dataset.xlsx")
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
ct = []
kc = []
sb = []
for rowx in range(sheet.nrows):
    cols = sheet.row_values(rowx)
    ct.append(cols[1])
    kc.append(cols[2])
    sb.append(cols[3])

ct = np.asarray(ct[1:])
kc = np.asarray(kc[1:])
sb = np.asarray(sb[1:])

score, pvalue, _ = coint(sb,kc)
print(pvalue)
print(np.corrcoef(sb,kc))
```

PS: Apologies if I'm making a very obvious mistake. Quite new to programming and have tried various approaches.

Thanks!

---

**edit #1:**

This is what the data looks like:

```
           COTTON   COFFEE  SUGAR
1/1/2007    56.19   126.2   11.75
1/2/2007    56.19   126.2   11.75
1/3/2007    54.89   123.6   11.51
1/4/2007    54.56   125     11.27
1/5/2007    54.42   120.45  11.09
1/8/2007    54.53   120.1   11.16
1/9/2007    54.1    118.4   11.1
1/10/2007   53.93   120.75  11.12
1/11/2007   54.04   120.65  11.02
1/12/2007   54.7    120.3   10.93
1/15/2007   54.7    120.3   10.93
1/16/2007   54.92   121.65  10.91
1/17/2007   55.06   121.6   10.76
1/18/2007   54.53   119.75  10.71
1/19/2007   54.55   119.7   10.86
            ...     ...     ...
```

All of it is in the same format (including type) as the other file that seems to work correctly.

And output upon just printing these elements is:

```
[u'C' u'56.19' u'56.19' ..., u'69.02' u'70.5' u'70.22']
[u'' u'126.2' u'126.2' ..., u'134.8' u'135.95' u'137.85']
[u'' u'11.75' u'11.75' ..., u'14.23' u'14.43' u'14.37']
```

Comment: Can you please print sb and kc elements? Want to to see the data type of those elements.

Comment: re-check the current `.asarray()` outputs with **`[ Arr.dtype for Arr in ( ct, kc, sb ) ]`** and rather enforce the desired typing by `.asarray( aList, np.float64 )` so as to avoid inferred typing ( Excel files can sometimes have some nasty type-related surprises with a number being actually a text ... et al ).

Comment: @PritamPan: just edited the output + data format.

Comment: @boametaphysica that's what I was suspecting ...You get this error because you need to convert your data to a numeric type. Your array contains strings...

Comment: thanks a lot. I fixed it and it seems to solve the problem. had a random string parked somewhere in the data.. cleaned it up and seems to be working fine!